# running hive command through shell getting error

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
hive -e "select key from hbcv_table a where a.col2 like \'%hello friend%\'" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  >a.dat
```

getting errror like -

> unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Can any one please help how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to shield single-quote:

```
hive -e "select key from hbcv_table a where a.col2 like '%hello friend%'" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  >a.dat
```

Single quotes in the select statement should be passed to Hive literally. And within double-quotes, single quotes have literal meaning.